# GPGGA message has a negative age in the "age" field

Tags: raspberry-pi, gps

I have a base and rover (each connected to a Raspberry Pi). The base has an RTK fix and sends corrections to the rover via str2str on the RPi.
`str2str -in serial://ttyACM0:115200:8:o:1:off -out tcpsvr://<Rover's IP>:<PORT>`

The Raspberry Pi connected to the rover has this rtkrcv command running: `rtkrcv -s -o rover_rtkrcv.conf` (config file given below)

According the rover_rtkrcv.conf, I am logging the output to a log file called pos.log and also monitoring the output on a telnet port. The RTKRCV console recognizes the base and I get a fix solution after a while.
**rover_rtkrcv.conf**

```
# Configuration of Rover

console-passwd     =
console-timetype   =gpst    # (0:gpst,1:utc,2:jst,3:tow)
console-soltype    =deg    # (0:dms,1:deg,2:xyz,3:enu,4:pyl)
console-solflag    =1      # (0:off,1:std+2:age/ratio/ns)

# Rover input
inpstr1-type       =serial                      # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,7:ntripcli,8:ftp,9:http)
inpstr1-path       =ttyACM0:115200:8:o:1:off
inpstr1-format     =ubx                      # (0:rtcm2,1:rtcm3,2:oem4,3:oem3,4:ubx,5:ss2,6:hemis,7:skytraq,8:gw10,9:javad,10:nvs,15:sp3)

# Base input
inpstr2-type       =tcpcli              # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,7:ntripcli,8:ftp,9:http)
inpstr2-path       =10.241.16.156:9011
inpstr2-format     =rtcm3                # (0:rtcm2,1:rtcm3,2:oem4,3:oem3,4:ubx,5:ss2,6:hemis,7:skytraq,8:gw10,9:javad,10:nvs,15:sp3)

# Corrections input
inpstr3-type       =off        # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,7:ntripcli,8:ftp,9:http)
inpstr3-path       =
inpstr3-format     =sp3        # (0:rtcm2,1:rtcm3,2:oem4,3:oem3,4:ubx,5:ss2,6:hemis,7:skytraq,8:gw10,9:javad,10:nvs,15:sp3)

# Output 1
outstr1-type       =file    # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,6:ntripsvr)
outstr1-path       =pos.log  # Telnet 
outstr1-format     =llh       # (0:llh,1:xyz,2:enu,3:nmea)

# Output 2
outstr2-type       =off       # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,6:ntripsvr)
outstr2-path       =
outstr2-format     =llh       # (0:llh,1:xyz,2:enu,3:nmea)

# Logging
logstr1-type       =off        # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,6:ntripsvr)
logstr1-path       =
logstr2-type       =off        # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,6:ntripsvr)
logstr2-path       =
logstr3-type       =off        # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,6:ntripsvr)
logstr3-path       =

# Rover solution options
pos1-posmode    =kinematic              # (0:single,1:dgps,2:kinematic,3:static,4:movingbase,5:fixed,6:ppp-kine,7:ppp-static)
pos1-frequency  =2                     # (1:l1,2:l1+l2,3:l1+l2+l5)
pos1-soltype    =forward                # (0:forward,1:backward,2:combined)
pos1-elmask     =15                     # (deg)
# apply SNR mask to rover
pos1-snrmask_r  =off                    # (0:off,1:on)
# apply SNR mask to base
pos1-snrmask_b  =off                    # (0:off,1:on)
pos1-snrmask_L1 =30                     # (dBHz)
#pos1-snrmask_L1=38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38     # (dBHz)
pos1-snrmask_L2 =0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0      # (dBHz)
pos1-snrmask_L5 =0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0      # (dBHz)
pos1-dynamics   =on                     # (0:off,1:on)
pos1-tidecorr   =off                    # (0:off,1:on)
pos1-ionoopt    =brdc                   # (0:off,1:brdc,2:sbas,3:dual-freq,4:est-stec,5:ionex-tec,6:qzs-brdc,7:qzs-lex,8:vtec_sf,9 :vtec_ef,10:gtec)
pos1-tropopt    =saas                   # (0:off,1:saas,2:sbas,3:est-ztd,4:est-ztdgrad)
pos1-sateph     =brdc                   # (0:brdc,1:precise,2:brdc+sbas,3:brdc+ssrapc,4:brdc+ssrcom)
pos1-posopt1    =off                    # (0:off,1:on)
pos1-posopt2    =off                    # (0:off,1:on)
pos1-posopt3    =off                    # (0:off,1:on)
pos1-posopt4    =off                    # (0:off,1:on)
pos1-posopt5    =off                    # (0:off,1:on)
pos1-exclsats   =                       # (prn ...)
pos1-navsys     =7                      # (1:gps+2:sbas+4:glo+8:gal+16:qzs+32:comp)

# Base station solution options
pos2-armode     =continuous           # (0:off,1:continuous,2:instantaneous,3:fix-and-hold,4:ppp-ar)
pos2-gloarmode  =on           # (0:off,1:on,2:autocal)
pos2-arthre     =1.3
pos2-arlockcnt  =0
pos2-thresar2   =0.9999
pos2-thresar3   =0.2
pos2-lockcntfixamb      =0
pos2-fixcntholdamb      =10
pos2-arelmask           =15             # (deg)
pos2-arminfix           =0
pos2-elmaskhold         =0
pos2-aroutcnt           =100
pos2-maxage             =0.1
pos2-slipthres          =0.05
pos2-rejionno           =1000
pos2-rejgdop            =30
pos2-niter              =3
pos2-baselen            =0
pos2-basesig            =0

# Output solution format
out-solformat   =nmea                    # (0:llh,1:xyz,2:enu,3:nmea)
out-outhead     =on                     # (0:off,1:on)
out-outopt      =on                     # (0:off,1:on)
out-timesys     =gpst                   # (0:gpst,1:utc,2:jst)
out-timeform    =hms                    # (0:tow,1:hms)
out-timendec    =3
out-degform     =deg                    # (0:deg,1:dms)
out-fieldsep    =
out-height      =ellipsoidal            # (0:ellipsoidal,1:geodetic)
out-geoid       =internal               # (0:internal,1:egm96,2:egm08_2.5,3:egm08_1,4:gsi2000)
out-solstatic   =all                    # (0:all,1:single)
out-nmeaintv1   =0                      # (s)
out-nmeaintv2   =0                      # (s)
out-outstat     =residual               # (0:off,1:state,2:residual)

# Statistics
stats-errratio     =100
stats-errphase     =0.003      # (m)
stats-errphaseel   =0.003      # (m)
stats-errphasebl   =0          # (m/10km)
stats-errdoppler   =1          # (Hz)
stats-stdbias      =30         # (m)
stats-stdiono      =0.03       # (m)
stats-stdtrop      =0.3        # (m)
stats-prnaccelh    =0.25       # (m/s^2)
stats-prnaccelv    =0.1        # (m/s^2)
stats-prnbias      =0.0001     # (m)
stats-prniono      =0.001      # (m)
stats-prntrop      =0.0001     # (m)
stats-clkstab      =5e-12      # (s/s)

# Misc options
misc-timeinterp         =off    # (0:off,1:on)
misc-sbasatsel          =0      # (0:all)
misc-rnxopt1            =
misc-rnxopt2            =
misc-svrcycle      =10         # (ms)
misc-timeout       =10000      # (ms)
misc-reconnect     =10000      # (ms)
misc-nmeacycle     =5000       # (ms)
misc-buffsize      =32768      # (bytes)
misc-navmsgsel     =rover       # (0:all,1:rover,2:base,3:corr)
misc-proxyaddr     =
misc-fswapmargin   =30         # (s)
misc-startcmd      =
misc-stopcmd       =

# Rover antenna
ant1-postype    =llh                            # (0:llh,1:xyz,2:single,3:posfile,4:rinexhead,5:rtcm)
ant1-pos1       =0                              # (deg|m)
ant1-pos2       =0                              # (deg|m)
ant1-pos3       =0                              # (m|m)
ant1-anttype    =
ant1-antdele    =0                              # (m|m)
ant1-antdeln    =0                              # (m|m)
ant1-antdelu    =0                              # (m|m)

# Base station antenna
# use "rtcm" if base station position transmitted in RTCM stream
# use "llh" and specify position in ant2-pos[123] (lat,lon.hgt) if not
ant2-postype    =rtcm                          # (0:llh,1:xyz,2:single,3:posfile,4:rinexhead,5:rtcm)
ant2-pos1       =                              # (deg|m) 49.4286786
ant2-pos2       =                              # (deg|m) 7.7510678
ant2-pos3       =                              # (m) 303.1 
ant2-anttype    =
ant2-antdele    =0                              # (m|m)
ant2-antdeln    =0                              # (m|m)
ant2-antdelu    =                               # (m|m)

# Files
file-cmdfile1           =
file-cmdfile2           =
file-cmdfile3           =
file-satantfile         =/usr/share/rtklib/ngs_abs.pcv
file-rcvantfile         =/usr/share/rtklib/igs05.atx
file-staposfile         =
file-geoidfile          =
file-ionofile           =
file-dcbfile            =/usr/share/rtklib/P1C1_ALL.DCB
file-eopfile            =
file-blqfile            =
file-tempdir            =
file-geexefile          =
file-solstatfile        =
file-tracefile          =
```

Thank you.

Questions:

1. Why am I seeing GPGGA messages instead of GNGGA messages? (When I use str2str, I see GNGGA messages)
2. Why is my "age" in the log file negative?
3. How can I check from the log file if I am receiving corrections from the base?
4. Why is the frequency of logging low, approximately every 20s. GNGGA messages would log every 1 second.